# Move lines 2 3 after line 5 using awk

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have file content as:

```
this line 1 no un1x
this lines 22 0
butbutbut this 33 22 has unix
but not 1
THIS is not
butbutbut ffff
second line
```

---

```
awk 'NR==2 && NR==3 {f=$0;next}  NR ==5 &&f{print;print f}' awk.write
```

The problem here that in `f` I can only save value of `nr==3` I want to move the lines 2 and 3 after line 5.

Comment: What is with the other lines? Should they be printed too, or only line 5 and then 2 and 3?

Comment: yes other lines should follow through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way:

```
awk 'NR==2 || NR==3{a[i++]=$0;next}1;NR==5{for(j=0;j<2;j++){print a[j];}}' file
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
$ awk '
  FNR == 2 { l2 = $0; next } # Save 2nd line
  FNR == 3 { l3 = $0; next } # Save 3rd line
  FNR == 5 {                 # Print 5th line, follow 2nd, 3rd
    print
    print l2
    print l3
    next
  }
  1                          # Print other lines
' <file
```

Note that if you will lose the 2nd and 3rd line if the file had less than five lines.

Comment: excellent, may i know at the `END` why print `l2 and l3` again?

Comment: @asadz: Just want to handle the case where file is less than five lines, but the solution will be complex. Added a note.

Comment: Thank you, I've used it in a loop, to move the 1st line after the 6th (lines 1,7,13,19...): 
`awk '(FNR%6) == 1 {l = $0; next}
     (FNR%6) == 0 {print; print l; next}
     1'`

Answer (score 3):

```
awk 'NR == 2 || NR == 3 {l = l RS $0; next}
     NR == 5 {$0 = $0 l}
     {print}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You need multiple variables or an array. With `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==2||NR==3{a[i++]=$0;next} NR==5{print;for(c=0;c<i;c++){print a[c]}next}1' file
```

---

- `NR==2||NR==3` if it's line 2 or line 3

  - `a[i++]=$0;next` fill array `a` and continue.
- `NR==5` if it's line 5

  - `print` first print the line.
  - `for(c=0;c<i;c++){print a[c]}` loop trough the array and print its contents.
- `1` is a true condition to print each line.

Comment: Thanks, but did you run this cmd? I don't think it delivers the right results

Comment: Note that `for (i in a)` returned in unspecified order, so line 2 can become after line3.

Comment: @asadz I corrected the command